# put recaptcha response into a knockout js observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using google recaptcha and what I am trying to do is put the response into a observable and then send it to the backend server. I am trying but I am failing. Here are the codes.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
     <div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="############"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next piece of code is in the js file with knockout

```
self.recaptchaCode = ko.observable($('.g-recaptcha-response').val()); // Does not work
```

Here is the ajax sending to the backend

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: BASEURL + 'index.php/login/loginUsingAjax/' + auth,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: ko.toJSON({
                    email : self.eMail(),
                    password : self.passWord(),
                    recaptcha : self.recaptchaCode()
                })
            })
```

I guess I am not getting the right way to get the response into the observable

Comment: First: `recaptcha : self.self.recaptchaCode()` self is doubled, are you positively sure that `$('.g-recaptcha-response')` is in dom when you are try to reading its value try `console.log($('.g-recaptcha-response'))`

Comment: ya sorry the recaptcha self was a type copy pasting, but console.log shows undefined

Comment: @cske nope its not in the dom, it was showing in a tutorial to use it like that, and i also did try $('.g-recaptcha')

Comment: then it is not a knockout problem, wait for the recaptcha apears in dom, then read it's value

Comment: yea, i did, then i clicked not a robot, but there was no value inside the observable when i alerted it or console.logged it @cske

Comment: check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jaGWY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
self.recaptchaCode = ko.observable($('.g-recaptcha-response').val());
```

Sets the observable with the value your element holds *at the time the observable is created*. When you request the observable's value (`self.recaptchaCode()`), it is **not** re-evaluated; you receive a cached response.

This means your code will only work if the element's value is available at the time you instantiate your viewmodel. Knockout cannot magically watch a non data-bound DOM element.

I'd suggest creating a method instead of an observable:

```
self.getRecaptchaCode = function() { 
  return $('.g-recaptcha-response').val();
};
```

Better would be to create a `value` binding on the element, but I'm not sure if you have access to the `.g` part of the DOM... In that case, you could use a "real" knockout approach:

```
<input data-bind="value: recaptchaCode">
```

With `self.recaptchaCode = ko.observable()` in your viewmodel.